# What does the manifest.XML and other Yeoman Generator files actually do?

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

I am new to developing Office add-ins but I have a good understanding of front-end web development.

The Yeoman Generator is great as it gets you up and running quickly however I lack any understanding of what the files it produces do and how they work together to make the app work. I can't find any explanation in Microsoft's documentation, it seems limited to the Javascript API. The files/folders I am referring to are listed at the end of this post.

An example of this being a problem for me is that I have often found myself missing references to .js and .html files in the 'webpack.config.js' file. I have no idea what this file does and it was only after websearching the error did I find out that I needed to add a reference to this file. I also haven't found it particularly clear where and how I should reference the dialogbox API 1.2.

Is there any documentation online that will explain this to me? Thanks for your help.

Files that I do not know what they do:

```
.eslintrc.json
babel.config.json
manifest.xml
package-lock.json
package.json
tconfig.json
webpack.config.js
```

Folders that I do not know what they do:

```
.azure-devops/
.vscode/
assets/
node_modules/
```

Answer (score 0):

From your list, only manifest.xml is specific to Office Add-ins. It contains information about the add-in that Office needs to launch and run the add-in. There is extensive documentation about it. Start here: [Office Add-ins manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-in-manifests?tabs=tabid-1).

All of the others are common artifacts of web application development. I suggest that you search for information about each of them. E.g., "What is the .eslintrc.json file?"